Convergence of power series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{3^n(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}x^n$
$n!!$ is the double factorial, i.e. $6!! = 6\cdot4\cdot2$ and $9!! = 9\cdot7\cdot5\cdot3\cdot1$.
Let $a_n = \frac{3^n(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}x^n$, then using d'Alembert's test we get $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} |\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}| = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{3(2n+1)!!(2n)!!}{(2n+2)!!(2n-1)!!}|x| = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{3(2n+1)}{2n+2}|x| = 3|x|$. We want $3|x| < 1 \iff |x| < \frac 1 3$ so the radius of convergence is $\frac 1 3$. To find the interval we need to check the endpoints $\pm \frac 1 3$.
Let $x = \frac 1 3$: Using Raabe's test we get $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}n(\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}} - 1) = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} n(\frac{2n+2}{2n+1} - 1) = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{n}{2n+1} = \frac 1 2 < 1 \implies$ the series is divergent.
Let $x=-\frac 1 3$: The series is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}$. We can use Leibniz's test. The double factorial is monotonically increasing therefore $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!} = 0$. $\frac{(2(n+1) - 1)!!}{(2(n+1))!!} < \frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!} \iff \frac{(2n+1)!!}{(2n+2)!!} < \frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!} \iff 2n+1 < 2n+2$ which is true and therefore the sequence is monotonically decreasing. By Leibniz's test we know the series is convergent.
Finally we get that the radius of convergence is $\frac 1 3$ and the interval of convergence is $[-\frac 1 3, \frac 1 3)$.
Is my solution correct?

Yes, your solution is correct. Can you explain why you think it is wrong?

You could also use the fact that this is the expansion of $(1-3x)^{-\frac12}-1$, so you can use the convergence of the binomial expansion to show this.
